# Update Kendo Grid Column(Foreign Key) on Javascript Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So i am new to kendo controlles in MVC.

I have below .cshtml file.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AssetDeprGroupViewModel>()
        .Name("AssetDeprGrid")
        .Columns(c =>
        {                
            c.Bound(p => p.AssetDeprGroup).Title("Depr Group").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" }).ClientTemplate("<span title='#=data.AssetDeprGroup#'>#=data.AssetDeprGroup#</span>").Width(85);
            c.ForeignKey(p => p.AssetDeprClass, data2).Title("Class").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" }).Width(53);                                    
            c.Group(gr => gr
            .Title("AMT").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
                .Columns(info =>
                {
                    info.ForeignKey(p => p.MethodAMT, data1).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" }).Title("Method").Format("{0:p0}").Width(41);
                    info.ForeignKey(p => p.ConventionAMT, data).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" }).Title("Convention").Width(41);
                    info.Bound(p => p.LifeAMT).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" }).Title("Life").Width(25);                    
                })
                );               
            c.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit(); command.Destroy();
            }).Visible(hasCRUDpermission)                                      
                .Width(55)
                .Title("Action")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" })
                .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" });
        })

        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Events(e => e.Sync("sync_handler").Change("autoPopulate"))                                                
            .Read("GetAssetDeprGroups", "ProjectManagement")
            .Create("CreateAssetGroups", "ProjectManagement")
            .Update(update=>update.Action("UpdateAssetGroups", "ProjectManagement").Data("additionalInfo"))
            .Destroy("DeleteAssetGroups", "ProjectManagement")
```

So on my change event i am calling below javascript.

```
 function autoPopulate(e) {
        if (e.action == 'itemchange' && e.field == 'AssetDeprClass') {            
            //var grid = $("#AssetDeprGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var assetClassUrl = "@Url.Content("~/ProjectManagement/GetAssetDeprClass")";
            var assetClass = $("#AssetDeprClass").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: assetClassUrl,
                type: "POST",
                data: { assetClass: assetClass },
                success :function(d) {                    
                    var classData = d.Data[0];                    

                    $("#LifeAMT").val(classData.LifeAMT).toString();
                    $("#MethodAMT").val(classData.MethodAMT).toString();
                   $("#ConventionAMT").val(classData.ConventionAMT).toString();                                               }            
            });
        }
    };
```

The columns are updating fine with the latest data hwen we submit but the columns with foreign key are not reflecting their value on grid dropdown. It shows the same data as previous.

Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure that the elements that your trying to update have those ids? I see the where your binding the columns but I don't see where you are setting their ids. Your function is calling them by id.

Comment: Yes i think those elements have ids because when i am getting the data with this ids its coming fine. Just not changing the values on UI side.

Answer (score 0):

data, data1 and data2 should be  Enumerable type and include key and value then you should specify key and value in the ForeignKey column

for example  if MethodAMT is your foreignkey:

```
info.ForeignKey(p => p.MethodAMT, data1 , "MeshodAMT" ,"MeshodAMTTitle").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" }).Title("Method").Format("{0:p0}").Width(41);
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply but i already has hardcoded value to data, data1 as below.

SelectList data1 = new SelectList(item, "methodValue", "methodText");